# run Swing Applications (jar) from host server to remote machine

Tags: java, swing

I would like to ask how to run Swing Applications from host server to a remote machine.. for example..

I have a server which has a jar file build as swing application in linux and a web page that will run the jar file..

and remote machines will just type the URL for them to load the webpage and emulate/run the jar and display the swing application to the remote machine from the server.. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the swing app? Have you considered to remake the application into e.g. restful Spring app for logic, and making the front end (GUI) in one of the JavaScript frameworks?

Comment: doing some google search with keywords "jnlp swing example" will list lots of useful links

Comment: Basically I would like to run a swing application to a browser..

Comment: An [Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) can run embedded within the browser, [Webstart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) can launch a Swing application that is hosted remotely

Comment: @copeg *"An Applet can run embedded within the browser"* Not any more. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). *"Webstart can launch a Swing application that is hosted remotely"* That is the way to go here, though browser manufacturers have even made that harder in recent times.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson RE Applets...well its about time. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @copeg *"Well its about time"* Long overdue, even according to SO's top ranked answer provider for both the [applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) **&** [japplet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/japplet/topusers) tags (i.e. me). The majority  (I'd say 99%) of people forced to work on applets these days are students that have professors/teachers whose material is 10 years out of date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Webswing](http://webswing.org/#!/home) runs java swing applications on server machine and show GUI to user in browser and it is free. I tested it with our application and it is quite good and done its job.

From webswing site :

> What is Webswing ?
>
> Webswing is a web server that allows to run any
>   swing application inside your web browser using only pure HTML5.

You can download from [here](http://webswing.org/#!/downloads).